# Update winform DataGridView from another Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a winform task event that will send email report at specified time in my task scheduler class.

**taskEvent.cs**

```
public partial class taskEvent : Form
{
    //trigger task scheduler
    void triggerItem_OnTrigger(object sender, TaskScheduler.OnTriggerEventArgs e)
    {
        //Some other codes that generate report and specified formated filename on trigger.

        //send report on time scheduled
        SendMail(filename);
    }

    private void sendMail(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
          //send filename report as attachment
          SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
       updateLogs();
    }

   public void updateLogs()
   {
       //update log datagridview in another form.
       //update filename,datedelivered,status.
   }
}
```

Now when the email successfully send, I want it to add new row at the datagridview of my logForm. The logForm will ale to see the filename, datedeliverd and status of email.

**logForm.cs**

```
| Filename |    Date Delivered     |   Status     |  
|----------|-----------------------|--------------|  
| test123  | Friday, ‎July ‎04, ‎2014 | Delivered    |  
|          |                       |              |
```

Is it possible to add list to the data gridview in the logForm from my taskEvent form? Please advise how is this possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and it is quite simple with the following steps:

- Add a method onto your log form that is public and take a class representing the data you want to log.
- Make this new method add to the grid
- Create a reference to the log form on your task form by storing it in a variable
- Make calls to the public method when you want to log events

**edit**

So point 3 you need something like this, obviously when you construct your TaskForm you need to assign this variable with an instantiated LogForm.

```
class TaskForm : Form
{
   public LogForm MyLogForm;

   public void updateLogs()
   {
       MyLogForm.UpdateLog(new LogEntry());
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks Ian, i get you for the 1st and 2nd point. A bit confuse on the 3rd and 4th. you mean pass the variable from the task to the log? can this method update gridview at real time?

Comment: @Ren - Have edited my answer a little to help clarify.

Comment: tq, meaning that 1st I need to create a class in other saperated class files, then 2nd specified to store value in task form, 3rd is to call public method in log form in task form? correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @Ren: I don't understand your question I'm afraid

Comment: okay, what I mean is for your first point, I need to first create a new class in a new separate class file rite?